# Finding the maximum of the sum of different columns grouped by a category

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

This is my data set

[image: My_Data_Set]

I want to find out which are the most popular products in each country.

I've tried

```
SELECT
    "Country", 
    MAX(Ft, Vg, Mt),
    SUM("Fruit") AS Ft,
    SUM("Veg") AS Vg,
    SUM("Meat") AS Mt,
FROM
    "My_Data_Set"
GROUP BY
    ("Country");
```

Amongst a lot of other things but can't get anything to work.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Also, please don't use images, use editable text so that someone can copy your data if they want to try out a solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    CustomerId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Country VARCHAR(255),
    Fruit INTEGER,
    Veg INTEGER,
    Meat INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO customers (CustomerId, Country, Fruit, Veg, Meat) VALUES
(1, 'Spain', 100, 25, 60),
(2, 'USA', 20, 50, 150),
(3, 'India', 25, 20, 15),
(4, 'Germany', 35, 46, 75),
(5, 'Spain', 22, 36, 50),
(6, 'USA', 12, 34, 56),
(7, 'India', 67, 22, 38),
(8, 'Germany', 21, 45, 18);
```

---

**Query**

```
with cus as (
  select 
    distinct country, 
    sum(fruit) over(partition by country) as fruit, 
    sum(veg) over (partition by country) as veg, 
    sum(meat) over (partition by country) as meat 
  from 
    customers
) 
select 
  country, 
  case when fruit > veg 
  AND fruit > meat THEN 'fruit' WHEN veg > fruit 
  AND veg > meat THEN 'veg' WHEN meat > fruit 
  AND meat > veg THEN 'meat' end as popular_product 
from 
  cus;
```

| country | popular_product |
| --- | --- |
| Germany | meat |
| India | fruit |
| Spain | fruit |
| USA | meat |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vXHGbfXyzExvsgDhnk8J6y/5)

Comment: Hi Thanks so much for that - that worked brilliantly and helped me understand how to construct such queries

Comment: That's close, but it's incorrect because it will not return the most popular products of a country if different products are most popular. See https://dbfiddle.uk/BDCymCio. @Bala Shanmugam You still havent't taged your RDBMS. You should do that because the solutions depend on it.

Comment: By the way, your `CASE`  is very bad to read, you'll better use `GREATEST`: `CASE GREATEST(fruit,veg,meat) WHEN fruit THEN 'fruit' WHEN veg THEN 'veg' ELSE 'meat' END AS popular_product`, but the question what to do if different products are most popular raises anyway and must be clarified by the question's author.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, Ive tagged the RDBMS now. Apologies, I havent explained what I was looking for clearly. Essentially I want to output which product has the highest sales in each country

Comment: Also thanks for the suggestion of using GREATEST - that was very helpful